# I get this error when I say switch platform for android in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to make a game from unity for android, but when I select android from the build settings section and say switch platform, I get this error:

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.6\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs(754,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AndroidExternalToolsSettings' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I tried to update "Package manager UI" from Package manager section, but there was no "Package Manager UI" in my Package Manager section

Comment: Try closing unity and deleting the Library folder (this will be regenerated when you re-open the project (always back things up before deleting project files at the instruction of internet comments))

Answer (score 1):

Close the project file and open the project this error with get resolve